# Parse external files with grunt in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, gettext, grunt-angular-gettext

I am currently using angular-gettext in order to translate my app creating a .po file.

My problem is that I have a strange architecture, and my HTML views are not in the same project than my Angular app.

So I would like to know if it possible to make the gruntfile.js parse external views such as :

```
nggettext_extract: {
            pot: {
                files: {
                    'po/accred-front.pot': ['http://exemple-external-url.com/views/{,*/}*.html', '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js']
                }
            }
        },
```

Of course when I am writing the code above, the genereated .pot file is not updated with marked as translated strings ( for instance `<h1 translate>IDENTIFY</h1>` is not added to .pot file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently you can not parse external files. What I did is get all files via grunt-curl, and then parse them locally in order to get all translated keys.